# How do I get actionsObserver value from angular state

Tags: angular, state

I am using below line to view state data
`this.store.select(selectUser)`
It has data as expected under actionsObserve.

However I am not able to read the data in actionsObserve:
`this.store.select(selectUser).actionsObserver._value.payload`
I am getting Property 'actionsObserver' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Here is my response from this.store.select(selectUser):

```
Object { 
   actionsObserver: {
      _value: Object { 
           user: Object { id: "1", updatedAt: 0, … }
           type: "[User Details] Load user details success"
​​​      }
   }
   closed: false
   currentObservers: Array [ {…} ]
   hasError: false
   isStopped: false
   observers: Array [ {…} ]
   thrownError: null
​​}
operator: function operate(liftedSource)​
reducerManager: Object { closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, … }
source: Object { actionsObserver: {…}, reducerManager: {…}, source: {…}, … }
```

Not being able to get state data

Answer (score 0):

this error means that `this.store.select(selectUser)` is of type `Observable`

you can get its value simply by subscribing to it in typescript file

```
this.store.select(selectUser).subscribe((user) => user.actionsObserver._value.payload);
```

or if you are using it in html you can use `async` pipe directly

```
(this.store.select(selectUser))? | async).actionsObserver._value.payload
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am getting: Property 'actionsObserver' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339)

Comment: that's why it is wiser to add strict types in the original question
from the naming I assumed it returns the data of a single user
I guess that you want the `.actionsObserver._value.payload` for each user.
you can map the user data to the payload you need you can use ((users) => user.map((user) => user.actionsObserver._value.payload))`

Comment: As I mentioned, .actionsObserver exist when I print `this.store.select(selectUser)`. However I am still not able to print. I get the above mentioned error.